# how to change password for windows service accounts

Tags: windows, passwords

I have about 30 services accounts that I need to change password without having to login to a machine and Atl-Ctl-Del to change password. I dont have AD access. Is there other way that I am not thinking.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are these local or AD accounts? Which programming language are you using?

Comment: I tried SharePoint central admin to change the password but after few seconds of hour glass i get access denied. Same goes with when I use windows built in active directory users and computers.